# How to generate keystore only with C/O/OU/CN by JAVA keytool

Tags: java, keystore, ca

I'm using java keytool to generate keystore for server.
It contains

```
1.CN 
2.OU
3.O
4.L 
5.ST
6.C
```

But customize CA only has

```
1.CN
2.OU
3.O
4.C
```

How to generate keystore only with `C/O/OU/CN` by JAVA keytool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by 'customize CA'.

If you are talking about the **selfsigned** cert created automatically by `-genkeypair`, which doesn't actually involve any CA although it does have a *name* in Subject and Issuer, the latter of which would normally be a CA name:

- if using prompting answer the applicable questions and enter nothing (just CR) for the others
- if using `-dname` specify the desired attributes and don't specify the others

If you mean requesting a cert **from a CA**, you can control what goes in the *request* (CSR) with `-dname`, but the CA can ignore that; only the CA controls what goes in the cert, and since you haven't said anything about who the CA is, it's impossible to even attempt to answer.